# Data is Not Showing in Recycler View Layout

Tags: java, android

**//this is my internship_jobs.xml code //**

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:background="@color/toolbar_background_color"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:title="CAMPUS"
                app:titleMarginStart="40dp"
                app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarTitleText">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/bell_icon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/wallet"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:contentDescription="Bell Icon"/>

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

            <!-- LinearLayout with TextView -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/off"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Latest Internships"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="21sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                    android:gravity="center"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- RecyclerView -->
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/off"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**//this is my internship_card.xml code//**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:background="@color/toolbar_background_color"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:title="CAMPUS"
                app:titleMarginStart="40dp"
                app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarTitleText">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/bell_icon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/wallet"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:contentDescription="Bell Icon"/>

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="4dp"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:layout_margin="16dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="16dp">

                    <!-- Left side small image -->
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/dataImage"
                        android:layout_width="48dp"
                        android:layout_height="48dp"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

                    <!-- Right side text and button -->
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp">

                        <!-- Text -->
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/dataTitle"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"/>

                        <!-- Button -->
                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/dataLink"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Apply Now"
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>

                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

/**/this is my Intern model class code//**

```
// Model class file
package com.example.job.model;

public class Intern {

    private int imageResource;
    private String title;
    private String link;

    public Intern(int imageResource, String title, String link) {
        this.imageResource = imageResource;
        this.title = title;
        this.link = link;
    }

    public int getImageResource() {
        return imageResource;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }
}
```

**// this is my InternshipAdapter code //**

```
// Adapter File
package com.example.job.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.job.R;
import com.example.job.model.Intern;

import java.util.List;

public class InternAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<InternAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Intern> mInternList;

    public InternAdapter(Context context, List<Intern> internList) {
        mContext = context;
        mInternList = internList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.internship_card, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Intern currentItem = mInternList.get(position);

        holder.imageView.setImageResource(currentItem.getImageResource());
        holder.textViewTitle.setText(currentItem.getTitle());
        holder.buttonLink.setText(currentItem.getLink());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mInternList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView imageView;
        public TextView textViewTitle;
        public Button buttonLink;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dataImage);
            textViewTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dataTitle);
            buttonLink = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dataLink);
        }
    }
}
```

**// this is my MainActivity.java code //**

```
package com.example.job;

import com.example.job.adapter.InternAdapter;
import com.example.job.model.Intern;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;



import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.example.job.adapter.MainRecyclerAdapter;
import com.example.job.model.AllCategory;
import com.example.job.model.CategoryItem;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    Toolbar toolbar;

    RecyclerView mainCategoryRecycler;
    MainRecyclerAdapter mainRecyclerAdapter;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Inflate the menu

        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawerlayout);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationview);
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

           //recycler view

       // Find the RecyclerView in internship_jobs.xml layout
        View internshipJobsLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.internship_jobs, null);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = internshipJobsLayout.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView3);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        // Populate data
        List<Intern> internList = createInternList();

        // Initialize adapter and set to RecyclerView
        InternAdapter adapter = new InternAdapter(this, internList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigration_open, R.string.navigration_close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);

        // Set click listeners for the text views
        TextView offCampusTextView = findViewById(R.id.text_off_campus_jobs);
        TextView internshipsTextView = findViewById(R.id.internships_jobs);

        // logout Menu Implementation

        // Set a listener for navigation item clicks





        // logout Implementation Closed

        offCampusTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Navigate to OffCampusActivity
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, offcampusActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        internshipsTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Navigate to InternshipsActivity
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, InternshipsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });










        // added in first category
        List<CategoryItem> categoryItemList = new ArrayList<>();
        categoryItemList.add(new CategoryItem(1, R.drawable.hollywood1));
        categoryItemList.add(new CategoryItem(1, R.drawable.hollywood2));
        categoryItemList.add(new CategoryItem(1, R.drawable.hollywood3));
        categoryItemList.add(new CategoryItem(1, R.drawable.hollywood4));
        categoryItemList.add(new CategoryItem(1, R.drawable.hollywood5));
        categoryItemList.add(new CategoryItem(1, R.drawable.hollywood6));

        // added in second category
        List<CategoryItem> categoryItemList2 = new ArrayList<>();
        categoryItemList2.add(new CategoryItem(1, R.drawable.bestofoscar1));
        categoryItemList2.add(new CategoryItem(1, R.drawable.bestofoscar2));
        categoryItemList2.add(new CategoryItem(1, R.drawable.bestofoscar3));
        categoryItemList2.add(new CategoryItem(1, R.drawable.bestofoscar4));
        categoryItemList2.add(new CategoryItem(1, R.drawable.bestofoscar5));
        categoryItemList2.add(new CategoryItem(1, R.drawable.bestofoscar6));

        // added in 3rd category
        List<CategoryItem> categoryItemList3 = new ArrayList<>();
        categoryItemList3.add(new CategoryItem(1, R.drawable.moviedubbedinhindi1));
        categoryItemList3.add(new CategoryItem(1, R.drawable.moviedubbedinhindi2));
        categoryItemList3.add(new CategoryItem(1, R.drawable.moviedubbedinhindi3));
        categoryItemList3.add(new CategoryItem(1, R.drawable.moviedubbedinhindi4));
        categoryItemList3.add(new CategoryItem(1, R.drawable.moviedubbedinhindi5));
        categoryItemList3.add(new CategoryItem(1, R.drawable.moviedubbedinhindi6));




        // added in 5th category

        List<CategoryItem> categoryItemList5 = new ArrayList<>();
        categoryItemList5.add(new CategoryItem(1, R.drawable.bestofoscar1));
        categoryItemList5.add(new CategoryItem(1, R.drawable.bestofoscar2));
        categoryItemList5.add(new CategoryItem(1, R.drawable.bestofoscar3));
        categoryItemList5.add(new CategoryItem(1, R.drawable.bestofoscar4));
        categoryItemList5.add(new CategoryItem(1, R.drawable.bestofoscar5));
        categoryItemList5.add(new CategoryItem(1, R.drawable.bestofoscar6));
        List<AllCategory> allCategoryList = new ArrayList<>();
        allCategoryList.add(new AllCategory("Learn How To Use AI Tools", categoryItemList));
        allCategoryList.add(new AllCategory("Digital Mastery: Web Development", categoryItemList2));
        allCategoryList.add(new AllCategory("Digital Mastery: App Developemnt", categoryItemList3));
        allCategoryList.add(new AllCategory("Graphic Design Development", categoryItemList5));

        setMainCategoryRecycler(allCategoryList);

     //Text View Redirection Code






    }


    private void setMainCategoryRecycler(List<AllCategory> allCategoryList){

        mainCategoryRecycler = findViewById(R.id.main_recycler);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mainCategoryRecycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mainRecyclerAdapter = new MainRecyclerAdapter(this, allCategoryList);
        mainCategoryRecycler.setAdapter(mainRecyclerAdapter);

    }

    private List<Intern> createInternList() {
        List<Intern> internList = new ArrayList<>();
        internList.add(new Intern(R.drawable.lock, "Internship Title 1", "Link 1"));
        internList.add(new Intern(R.drawable.lock, "Internship Title 2", "Link 2"));
        internList.add(new Intern(R.drawable.lock, "Internship Title 3", "Link 3"));
        // Add more items as needed
        return internList;
    }



}
```

When I run My app and move to page internship_jobs.xml it is showing blank

I have attempted various methods and approaches, but unfortunately, I have been unable to resolve the issue. Each time I run my app, it navigates to the internships_jobs.xml layout, which appears blank, with the RecyclerView failing to populate data.

Comment: Why is layout of item wrapped to `DrawerLayout` and `ScrollView`? Set the root item layout to `ConstraintLayout` only.